# AttributeError : module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib' - python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am working on a upgrading project from **Tensorflow 1.15 to 2.4.1** ( python 3.8 ). The following is the issue I am facing.
I understand the issue is with tf.contrib. How do I make this work ?

```
if num_epochs is not None and shuffle:
        dataset = dataset.apply(
            tf.contrib.data.shuffle_and_repeat(buffer_size=batch_size * 10, count=num_epochs)
        )
    elif shuffle:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=batch_size * 10)
    elif num_epochs is not None:
        dataset = dataset.repeat(count=num_epochs)

    dataset = dataset.apply(
        tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch(map_func=parse_csv,
                                      batch_size=batch_size,
                                      num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    )

    I have another block below

    distribution_strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy(num_gpus=num_gpus,
                                                                   prefetch_on_device=True,
                                                                   auto_shard_dataset=True)
```

How do I achieve the same in Tensorflow 2.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.contrib` is no longer exist in tf2. Your converted code in tf2 is something like this:

```
if num_epochs is not None and shuffle:
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(batch_size * 10).repeat(num_epochs)
elif shuffle:
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(batch_size * 10)
elif num_epochs is not None:
    dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)

dataset = dataset.map(parse_csv, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE).batch(batch_size)

distribution_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
```

Comment: in recent versions of tensorflow, `AUTOTUNE` is in `tf.data.AUTOTUNE`

Comment: @jakub Yes. I forgot to change it. Thank you